# Выпадающее меню в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Всем привет, помогите решить проблемку. Дело в том, что нужно в мобильной версии, в меню при нажатии на раздел выпадал подменю. Но на разделе уже есть ссылка, и надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии первый раз открывалось подменю, а со второго раза уже можно было перейти в раздел. До этого было по другому, справа от раздела стоял +, если есть подменю, и при клике на него открывалось подменю, но нужно сейчас избавить от + и сделать так. Конечно решить это хотелось бы без редактирования html, так как шаблон купленный и часто обновляется, а использовать custom css и js есть возможность.

```html
<div class="menu_wrapper">
  <nav id="menu" class="menu-main-menu-container" style="display: block;">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-2566" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children submenu"><a href="/o-kompanii"><span>О КОМПАНИИ</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2922" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/istoriya-sozdaniya"><span>ИСТОРИЯ СОЗДАНИЯ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2574" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="tseli-i-zadachi/"><span>ЦЕЛИ И ЗАДАЧИ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2570" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/novosti"><span>НОВОСТИ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2567" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/vakansii"><span>ВАКАНСИИ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2572" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/partneryi"><span>ПАРТНЕРЫ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2571" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page last-item"><a href="/otzyivyi"><span>ОТЗЫВЫ</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2789" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children submenu"><a><span>АВТОПАРК</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2576" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page last-item"><a href="/avtopark/shemyi-tralov"><span>СХЕМЫ ТРАЛОВ</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children submenu"><a><span>НАШИ РАБОТЫ</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2577" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page last-item"><a href="/nashi-rabotyi/foto-tehniki"><span>ФОТО ТЕХНИКИ</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2583" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children submenu"><a href="/perevozka-gruzov"><span>ПЕРЕВОЗКА ГРУЗОВ</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2584" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/perevozka-gruzov/vidyi-osobennosti"><span>ВИДЫ, ОСОБЕННОСТИ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/perevozka-gruzov/perevozka-stroitelnoy-tehniki"><span>ПЕРЕВОЗКА СТРОИТЕЛЬНОЙ ТЕХНИКИ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2709" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/perevozka-gruzov/perevozka-oborudovaniya"><span>ПЕРЕВОЗКА ОБОРУДОВАНИЯ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2791" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/perevozka-gruzov/perevozka-negabaritnyih-gruzov-2"><span>ПЕРЕВОЗКА НЕГАБАРИТНЫХ ГРУЗОВ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/perevozka-gruzov/perevozka-sverhnegabaritnyih-gruzov"><span>ПЕРЕВОЗКА СВЕРХНЕГАБАРИТНЫХ ГРУЗОВ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2710" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page last-item"><a href="/perevozka-gruzov/perevozka-tyazelovesnyh-gruzov/"><span>ПЕРЕВОЗКА ТЯЖЕЛОВЕСНЫХ ГРУЗОВ</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2790" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children submenu"><a><span>ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ УСЛУГИ</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2696" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/dopolnitelnyie-uslugi/soprovozhdenie-i-ohrana-gruzov/"><span>СОПРОВОЖДЕНИЕ И ОХРАНА ГРУЗОВ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2695" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/dopolnitelnyie-uslugi/obsledovanie-marshruta/"><span>ОБСЛЕДОВАНИЕ МАРШРУТА</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2694" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/dopolnitelnyie-uslugi/pogruzochnyie-i-razgruzochnyie-rabotyi/"><span>ПОГРУЗОЧНЫЕ И РАЗГРУЗОЧНЫЕ РАБОТЫ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2693" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/dopolnitelnyie-uslugi/professionalnyie-takelazhnyie-rabotyi/"><span>ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНЫЕ ТАКЕЛАЖНЫЕ РАБОТЫ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2692" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/dopolnitelnyie-uslugi/arenda-spets-tehniki/"><span>АРЕНДА СПЕЦ. ТЕХНИКИ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2691" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/dopolnitelnyie-uslugi/strahovanie/"><span>СТРАХОВАНИЕ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2697" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom last-item"><a href="http://stone-xxi.ru/"><span>ЛИЗИНГ</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children submenu last"><a><span>ДОКУМЕНТЫ</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2579" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="/dokumentyi/vnutrennie-dokumentyi/"><span>ВНУТРЕННИЕ ДОКУМЕНТЫ</span></a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2604" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page last-item"><a href="/dokumentyi/zakonodatelnyie-aktyi/"><span>ЗАКОНОДАТЕЛЬНЫЕ АКТЫ</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="menu-toggle"></span>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2581" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page last"><a href="/kontaktyi/"><span>КОНТАКТЫ</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav><a class="responsive-menu-toggle  active" href="#"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: выложите ваш код, который не работает, и тогда вероятность получения вами ответа повысится. ведь проще найти ошибку в вашем коде, чем писать всё с нуля.

Comment: @lexxl, а я разве в тексте указал, что у меня ошибка в коде?

Comment: я имел ввиду не только html

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте тем ссылкам, переход по которым должен происходить только после второго клика, какой-нибудь сигнальный класс (например, `noclick`), если не хочется редактировать шаблон, то добавлять его можно с помощью js. При клике по ссылке отменяйте дефолтное поведение и проверяйте наличие этого класса. Если класс есть - удаляйте его и разворачивайте меню. Если класса нет - производите переход.

Comment: Спасибо, но дело такое, что я логически понимаю, как сделать, а на практике не понимаю. Не знаю кода JavaScript